# Regex | Pattern attribute value is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation, input

I inject some Regex string to input element's pattern attribute via javascript (depending on some form changes out of context) and it works as expected but the thing is, it logs an error to the console when I focus on the input for the very first time.

I've tried to escape the regex as you can see below but then HTML input failed to validate the corresponding value according to the pattern used before.

required regex code

`(\(?([\d \-\)\–\+\/\(]+){6,}\)?([ .\-–\/]?)([\d]+))`

and that's how i define and inject it via JS

`/([\d \-\)\–\+\/\(]+){6,}\)?([ .\-–\/]?)([\d]+)/g`

and here's what I tried and **failed while trying to escape** it for HTML pattern attribute

`([\d \-)–+/(]+){6,}\)?([.-–/]?)([\d]+)`

I'm really seeking a way to achieve all these without any errors:

- regex will be used in JS to `match` with the input value and only proceed if it's valid
- it will also be used in HTML as a **pattern attribute** to give user feedback about input validation hopefully without any errors like this one; `Pattern attribute value /(\(?([\d \-\)\–\+\/\(]+){6,}\)?([ .\-–\/]?)([\d]+))/g is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //(\(?([\d \-\)\–\+\/\(]+){6,}\)?([ .\-–\/]?)([\d]+))/g/: Invalid escape`

Comment: Before any escaping, your `([\d \-\)\–\+\/\(]+){6,}` makes no sense. You match one or more chars in the char class 6 or more times. What should the pattern match?

Comment: To validate a string, you will need to use `^your_pattern$`, add anchors.

Comment: Thnx for the response @WiktorStribiżew Pattern should match exactly the regex (which addresses the german phone numbers like these https://regex101.com/r/CAVex8/143 ) I'm happy with regex but my input pattern attribute is not :s

Comment: You need `/^\(?[\d +\/()–-]{6,}\)?[ .\/–-]?\d+$/` in `String#match` and `pattern="\(?[\d +\/()–-]{6,}\)?[ .\/–-]?\d+"`

Comment: Why is that? It resolves my needs. I'd love to hear your recommendation that will work well with the pattern attribute.

Comment: I mentioned that it makes no sense to match an *infinite* amount of chars *six or more* times. See my suggestion above.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @WiktorStribiżew Somehow i still get an error in console. `Pattern attribute value (?[d +/()–-]{6,})?[ ./–-]?d+ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?[d +/()–-]{6,})?[ ./–-]?d+/: Invalid group`

Comment: You are certainly not using them properly. Add the code for each case to the question.

Comment: Anyway, the regexp is not great, as it allows any amount of digits in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex itself is not really validating the phone numbers well, but since you are happy with the pattern, see below how it should be used in JS and HTML5 pattern attribute.

In JS, you need to use

```js
var rx = /^\(?[\d +\/()–-]{6,}\)?[ .\/–-]?\d+$/;
// Test
console.log(rx.test("02162 - 54 91 44 79"));
```

In a HTML5 `pattern` attribute, the anchors are redundant and the escaped chars should only be those that are allowed be escaped (i.e. `[\(\)]` -> `[()]`, etc.):

```css
input:valid {
  color: black;
  border: 5px solid #dadadada;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
input:invalid {
  color: navy;
  outline: none;
  border-color: #ff1050;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input pattern="\(?[\d +\/()–-]{6,}\)?[ .\/–-]?\d+" title="Please enter a valid phone number!" value="(02162) 54 91 44 79" />
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'll accept your answer but I really wonder what's the problem with my form since I still get this error in console `Pattern attribute value (?[d +/()–-]{6,})?[ ./–-]?d+ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?[d +/()–-]{6,})?[ ./–-]?d+/: Invalid group` correspoding html and JS code is in here: https://jsfiddle.net/0td6xrug/2/

Comment: There, you need `pattern="\s*[A-Za-z]+(?:(?:[.,]? |[-'])[A-Za-z]+)+\.?\s*"` for `name`.  The `phonePattern = new RegExp(/^\(?[\d +\/()–-]{6,}\)?[ .\/–-]?\d+$/);` must be declared as `const phonePattern = /^\(?[\d +\/()–-]{6,}\)?[ .\/–-]?\d+$/;`. And `let resolution = inputValue && !!inputValue.match(this.phonePattern);` must be `let resolution = inputValue && this.phonePattern.test(inputValue);`, but the main trouble is `inputEl.setAttribute('pattern', `\(?[\d +\/()–-]{6,}\)?[ .\/–-]?\d+`);`, it must be `inputEl.setAttribute('pattern', "\\(?[\\d +/()–-]{6,}\\)?[ ./–-]?\\d+");`.

Comment: See [this JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/2ngb37yo/5/)

Comment: Thank you! That pattern worked like a charm now. Since you've got pretty good regex knowledge, can I ask you why we have to change the regex string for pattern? What's the motivation behind it, any links articles are welcome. Once again, thank you very much Wiktor!

Comment: Ask me a quesion one by one, probably in  chat. There are too many things here. Actually, I do not get it what you mean by *why we have to change the regex string for pattern*. I changed to `^\(?[\d +\/()–-]{6,}\)?[ .\/–-]?\d+$` because hyphens at the end of the character classes does not have to be escaped, `(a+){6,}` makes no sense, anchors are necessary to make the regex be applied to the whole string.